# Get two closest numbers in a list using recursion in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I'm trying to use recursion to find the colosest numbers in a list.
I made a program that runs corectly without any errors but I want to know if there's a better way to right my program while still using recursion.

This is my program:

```py
deff = -1
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
def closest(List):
    global deff, num1, num2
    deff1 = -1
    if deff == -1:
        deff = max(List) - min(List)
        deff1 = max(List) - min(List)
    if len(List) == 1:
        deff = -1
        return [num1, num2]
    if abs(List[0] - List[1]) <= deff:
        deff = abs(List[0] - List[1])
        num1 = List[0]
        num2 = List[1]
    return closest(List[1:])
```

This is my Tester Program:

```py
from recursion import *
allPassed = True

def closestMain():
    global allPassed    
    testCases = [(1, [3, 7, 67, 68, 210, 215], [67, 68]),
                 (2, [3, 7, 67, 168, 210, 215], [3, 7]),
                 (3, [3, 47, 67, 168, 210, 215], [210, 215]),
                 (4, [3, 7], [3, 7]),
                 (5, [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3]),
                 (6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6]),
                 (7, [5, 10, 100, 105, 305, 310], [305, 310]),
                 (8, [5, 10, 15], [10, 15])]
    
    for num, L, expected in testCases:
        result = closest(L)
        if result != expected:
            print(f'Closest Test {num} Failed. Expected {expected} got {result}')
            allPassed = False

def main():
    closestMain()
    if allPassed:
        print('All tests passed')

    
main()
```

Again no errors, the program works fine, just trying to see if there's a better way to do it using recursion.

Assume the list is always sorted and assume the length is always greater or equal to 2

Comment: I think this question would probably get better answers on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Even beyond your code, I suggest that you write your test case using pytest or unittest.

Comment: I was provided with the tester program and asked to make the actual program. so I have no power over changing the tester program.

Comment: why not use `return allPassed` and later `if not closestMain(): print(...)` - without global variable

Comment: What's the provided problem specification? (Or at least, what does it say about the length and sortedness of the list?)

Comment: You say "no length constraints", but for length 0 your code *crashes*, contradicting *"runs corectly without any errors"*. And for length 1, the answer you accepted returns something different than your own code. Are you sure the list length doesn't have a ">= 2" constraint?

Comment: yes you're right assume it's always greater or equal to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my attempt, this algorithm works for sorted lists:

```
def closest(list_, close=None):
    if len(list_) < 2: return close
    if not close: return closest(list_[1:],list_[:2])
    a,b = list_[:2]
    x,y = close
    return closest(list_[1:], (a,b) if b-a <= y-x else (x,y))
```

Answer (score 1):

**decomposed recursion**

`closest` *could* be a recursive program, but it's a setup for a complex and tightly-coupled program. The high-level way to express the solution is using `min` and `combinations`, two generic functions, each of which *could* be implemented using recursion -

```py
from itertools import combinations

def closest(l):
  return min(combinations(l, 2), key=lambda pair: abs(pair[0] - pair[1]))
```

```py
tests = [
  (1, [3, 7, 67, 68, 210, 215], (67, 68)),
  (2, [3, 7, 67, 168, 210, 215], (3, 7)),
  (3, [3, 47, 67, 168, 210, 215], (210, 215)),
  (4, [3, 7], (3, 7)),
  (5, [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], (3, 3)),
  (6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], (5, 6)),
  (7, [5, 10, 100, 105, 305, 310], (305, 310)),
  (8, [5, 10, 15], (10, 15))
]

for num, lst, expected in tests:
  print(f"#{num} {expected} {closest(lst)}")
```

| no. | expected | actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (67, 68) | (67, 68) |
| 2 | (3, 7) | (3, 7) |
| 3 | (210, 215) | (210, 215) |
| 4 | (3, 7) | (3, 7) |
| 5 | (3, 3) | (3, 3) |
| 6 | (5, 6) | (1, 2) |
| 7 | (305, 310) | (5, 10) |
| 8 | (10, 15) | (5, 10) |

Notice the *earliest* closest numbers are returned, unlike the latest that are expected in your output. Using the built-in `min` function we cannot control which minimum is returned, however we can supply our own recursive implementations and get the output we expect -

```py
def combinations(t, n):
  if n <= 0:
    yield ()
  elif not t:
    return
  else:
    for x in combinations(t[1:], n - 1):
      yield (t[0], *x)
    yield from combinations(t[1:], n)

def min(t, key = lambda x: x):
  def loop(a):
    try:
      b = next(t)
      return loop(b if key(b) < key(a) else a)
    except StopIteration:
      return a
  return loop(next(t, None))
```

If we rerun the tests, we see the output is the same. So how can we control it?

**getting the exact output**

Because we wrote `min` we now have the power to change how it behaves. Instead of returning the earliest minimum value in the series, we can return the *latest*. This is easily accomplished by reordering the `if..else` -

```py
def min(t, key = lambda x: x):
  def loop(a):
    try:
      b = next(t)
      return loop(a if key(a) < key(b) else b) # <--
    except StopIteration:
      return a
  return loop(next(t, None))
```

Rerun the tests to see the updated output -

```py
for num, lst, expected in tests:
  print(f"#{num} {expected} {closest(lst)}")
```

| no. | expected | actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | (67, 68) | (67, 68) |
| #2 | (3, 7) | (3, 7) |
| #3 | (210, 215) | (210, 215) |
| #4 | (3, 7) | (3, 7) |
| #5 | (3, 3) | (3, 3) |
| #6 | (5, 6) | (5, 6) |
| #7 | (305, 310) | (305, 310) |
| #8 | (10, 15) | (10, 15) |

**using iterables correctly**

Writing `min` using recursion is a fun exercise, but there's a more ergonomic way to interact with python's iterables. The simple `for..in` loop is fast and doesn't risk overflowing the stack -

```py
def min(t, key = lambda x: x):
  a = next(t, None)
  for b in t:
    a = a if key(a) < key(b) else b
  return a
```

Rerun the tests and verify the output is identical.

Comment: You changed the number of comparisons from linear to quadratic. Not good.

Comment: thanks kelly. you assume the input list contains "closest" numbers that are already or adjacent or that the input list is already sorted. the question does not explicitly state either.

Answer (score 1):

Simple one without global variables and without changing the `closest(List)` signature ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVNNb4JAEL3zK6bpQWjWRsCvmHJoTD3ZpAdvhMOKiyVZgexC0sb42@nsriBU2g0O67x5b2bhUXyXn3nmLwtR1weWQMxzyWRpb1NZOisLcKUJcJaZDAQBeCatlmBlJTJQEDyBq/OUwB4CnQtXXqRzMYED5rriobuKnEZ/D2Og8IJFY4jv5EMlaYQYl@weV/KRZVmPichPmI0rIdM8g/RU5AInsyjnH1RKpobYiYpZVues7zTN7OtZjzzfUw63elwaKLFwTbEcFULbJRD6BBYE5uq3JOC5ExVmESImFzmkHbRdttdjur@pChom@gad/sVs94PsaaP9b4@ZQXvXleEPM@aI4sPwdC02QYW5Yuj7IGNhUDWtO9EB//k6uBPdrNkP0pcduj73decYf@iQ5AKy6kRgS4B9FSwu8UWm2e0ddh0kK152rem0GPryCj8Erc6qN1Mh0qy0k9HasGGnwhl7X2BDU84Oz/DWDHBuJC5wzLHKaF9GTk@x69QNRbcbq546Hu3ZtvmCWt5tQDPc6JVzfXIJhS7AhuZRGc26/gE)):

```
def closest(List):
    if len(List) == 2:
        return List * 1
    a, b = List[:2]
    c, d = closest(List[1:])
    if b - a < d - c:
        return [a, b]
    else:
        return [c, d]
```

Comment: this program assumes the closest numbers are already adjacent or that the input lists are sorted. [try it online](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCoMwEEX3nuIvTYnQaGtF6g16g5CFxkgFiZKki54@TQxCwYEZhveHN9vXvVddNZvxflQT5LJaZV3@mq0jbYZQ84RF6UTQdSgTjmWU@xiNGOECtvOeYkC3M96WYmeSYgzsX85ZK8jhH1CgxzMcFZAnPY/KJFKLVec86kWWbWbWLj@e8Iri9qCoQ5espmB1E7drHHdBiPc/)

Comment: @Mulan It assumes (1) that the OP is telling the truth when they say that their program is correct, (2) that the testing program (with all lists sorted) isn't misleading, and (3) that the OP didn't accept a wrong answer. But yes, that leads to the assumption that the actual problem specification guarantees the list to be sorted. And also that it guarantees it to have at least two elements (otherwise it would need to be specified what to).

Comment: nothing was misleading, i just wasn't looking for patterns where they weren't specifically called out

Comment: @Mulan I asked them and they confirmed sortedness and length>=2, see the question updates.